# Asp textbox not rendered as span in design page

Tags: html, asp.net

In my project I have a asp design page something like below

Design is working in local and not working in production here is my code below

```
<tr>
        <td><mons:ChannelizedImg id="reqimgReferenceName" runat="server" src="/clear.gif" alt=""></mons:ChannelizedImg>
            <mons:channelizedimg id="errimgReferenceName" Runat="server" SrcMsgId="284411" visible="false" AltMsgId="329686"></mons:channelizedimg>
        </td>
        <th scope="row" id="ReferenceName">
            <mons:monsmessage id="NameLabel" runat="server" MessageID="154305" ControlToLabel="txtReferenceName"></mons:monsmessage>
            <input id="hdnReferenceID" type="hidden" value="0" name="ReferenceID" runat="server"/>
        </th>
        <td><asp:textbox id="txtReferenceName" ToolTip="Reference Name" Runat="Server" CssClass="RequiredField" Columns="60" Width="250" MaxLength="100"></asp:textbox>
            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtReferenceName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*">!</asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <th scope="row"><mons:monsmessage ControlToLabel="txtCompany" id="CompanyLabel" runat="server" MessageID="154307"></mons:monsmessage></th>
        <td><asp:textbox id="txtCompany" ToolTip="Reference Company Name" Runat="Server" CssClass="NonRequiredField" Columns="60" Width="250" MaxLength="100"></asp:textbox></td>
    </tr>
```

but in the design output I cannot see the asp textbox control.

[image]

but in the page viewsource I can see the controls something like below

```
<tr>
        <td><img id="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_reqimgReferenceName" alt="" src="https://securemedia.newjobs.com/opm/www/usajobs/clear.gif" border="0" />

        </td>
        <th scope="row" id="ReferenceName">
            <span id="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_NameLabel"><label for="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_txtReferenceName">Name</label></span>
            <input name="MasterPage1:ResumeBodyContent:References1:hdnReferenceID" type="hidden" id="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_hdnReferenceID" value="0" />
        </th>
        <td><input name="MasterPage1:ResumeBodyContent:References1:txtReferenceName" type="text" maxlength="100" size="60" id="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_txtReferenceName" title="Reference Name" class="RequiredField" style="width:250px;" />
            <span controltovalidate="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_txtReferenceName" errormessage="Name is required" display="Dynamic" enabled="False" id="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_RequiredName" evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" initialvalue="" style="color:Red;display:none;">!</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <th scope="row"><span id="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_CompanyLabel"><label for="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_txtCompany">Company</label></span></th>
        <td><input name="MasterPage1:ResumeBodyContent:References1:txtCompany" type="text" maxlength="100" size="60" id="MasterPage1_ResumeBodyContent_References1_txtCompany" title="Reference Company Name" class="NonRequiredField" style="width:250px;" /></td>
    </tr>
```

but when I inspect element in mozilla firefox it renders as span

[image]

It's working in Local and not working in Production.

Can any one help to troubleshoot this

Answer (score -1):

try to set *TextMode = "MultiLine"* option to your textboxes. You wrote not clean, may be

Comment: make TextMode and delete Width property @Kapil